# Intervals as ordered couples in first-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

Suppose that, in first-order logic, I need to consider an ordered structure (such as time instants or ordered field). I begin with a binary predicate $≺$ to express the order:

$x ≺ y: x$ strictly precedes $y$.

And I impose the axioms of the total linear order:

$\forall x\neg(x ≺ x)$

$\forall x\forall y(x ≺ y \rightarrow \neg(y ≺ x)) $

$\forall x \forall y \forall z(x ≺ y ˄ y < z \rightarrow x ≺ z)$

$ \forall x \forall y(x = y ˅ x ≺ y ˅ y ≺ x)$

Now, I read that intervals can be defined as ordered couples, in such a way that intuitively $⟨x, y⟩$ is the interval that begins in x and ends in y. But I don't understand how to do this formally. What options there are to define the ordered couples in the object language?

My idea is that I need to introduce an unary predicate *I* for intervals and two unary function symbols *b* and *e* to express respectively the beginning and end-point of the intervals. So:

$I(x): x$ is an interval

$b(x):$ the beginning point of $x$

$e(x):$ the ending point of $x$

and say:

$\forall x\forall y(x ≺ y \rightarrow \exists z(I(z) ˄ b(z) = x ˄ e(z) = y))$

Is this enough? Or I need to introduce sets in the domain of discourse to say that $⟨x, y⟩$ is by definition equal to $\{\{x\}, \{x, y\}\}$? I'm confusing...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some of your choice as to how to formalize this will depend on how you are going to use this, and what you are trying to prove about it.  But, why not use a 2-place function symbol $int(x,y)$ that takes $x$ and $y$ and 'returns' an interval $<x,y>$?

Or, maybe use a 3-place predicate $Int(x,y,z)$ that says that $z$ is the interval $<x,y>$. So then you could do:

$$\forall x \forall y \forall z (Int(x,y,z) \rightarrow x < y)$$

to ensure that for an interval $<x,y>$ you indeed have $x<y$

Comment: Your idea to use a 2-place function symbol int(x, y) that takes the points x and y and returns an interval is clear to me. But my question is: the interval returned is an arbitrary individual in the domain of discourse. It is not the ordered couple <x, y> as such. In other words, the inteval is not by definition _the ordered couple <x, y>_, with the properties of ordered couples. Is it corrent? This means that writing <x, y> is only a useful metalinguistic abbreviation?

Comment: @Tony That's exactly right. So yes, you'd still need to provide a bunch of axioms to try and capture that you want this to mean an interval. Also, you immediately have a problem when $x>y$ ... in that case the expression $int(x,y)$ still needs to refer to *something* ... but what would that be? It can't be an interval, since $x > y$ .. so you'd need to map it to something else... which can be done (all you need to do is to say "well, that's just something else")... but maybe this is why the 3-place predicate might be a little cleaner. Again, I would say it depends on your purpose.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you very much!